# $db = new DB() confusion

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Can any please explain what does it mean

```
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

and it's giving me an Error

> "Error: Could not load database file mysql!"

file contents

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'XXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXX');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'XXXX');
```

DB CLASS Constructor

```
public function __construct($driver, $hostname, $username, $password, $database) {

        if (file_exists(DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php')) {

            require_once(DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php');

        } else {

            exit('Error: Could not load database file ' . $driver . '!');

        }



        $this->driver = new $driver($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    }
```

Comment: I've read title of your question as __$db = new confusion()__ - and, it seems. that's true

Comment: Provide more code, please. What throws the `Error: Could not load database file mysql!` error?

Comment: It is going to conntect to MySQL using some wrapper/active record class and it is failing to do so because of misconfiguration/wrong credentials/errors inside class/etc.

Comment: It's OpenCart, and it can't find/isn't including the `mysql.php` setup code.

Comment: @JeremySmyth it's fair also for some other ecommerce engines, too.

Comment: can any one please explain the New Db function and its which type of parameters it accept

Comment: @Ihsanchahi it is not a function, but a constructor of a `DB` _class_, parameters are options that are required by the mysql server to allow you to access its database(s)

Comment: Show us your DB class pls

Comment: public function __construct($driver, $hostname, $username, $password, $database) {

  if (file_exists(DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php')) {

   require_once(DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php');

  } else {

   exit('Error: Could not load database file ' . $driver . '!');

  }

    

  $this->driver = new $driver($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

 }

Comment: You don't have driver for mysql database, check DIR_DATABASE for existence of the mysql.php file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have driver for mysql database, check `DIR_DATABASE` folder for existence of the `mysql.php` file.

Comment: mysql.php is present in the directory and path is also correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using OpenCart, have a look in your `config.php` file. Find a line that looks like the following:

```
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/something/something/system/database/');
```

Make sure the `something/something` is valid for your site. In particular, ensure the path points to a directory containing the `mysql.php` driver file. You'll probably find it doesn't, so you'll need to edit it so that it does.

You should also check that the Apache service user has privileges to access that file.